# Why am I unable to define a array?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am unable to define a array in the android studio `mainActivityFragment.java`; it says it is unreachable statement.

My code is:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
                "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68"};
    }
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
    );
}
```

Comment: `foreCastArray` is not defined outside the scope of the function `onCreateView`

Comment: then how to create an array there ?

Comment: You need a `}` on the line after `return`

Comment: thanks amdixon it worked i put is out side didnt observe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
            "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
            "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
            "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
            "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
            "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68"};
}
```

you should put the `array` definition before the `return` statement

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] forecastArray = { "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40", "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
            "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
            "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
            "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
            "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68" };
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

hope that helped

Comment: This code won't compile, the `List` still needs to have access to the `forecastArray`.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] forecastArray` is defined as local variable in method `onCreateView`. Just move the definition outside that method. Then you can initialize it there.

Here's how you can do it:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] forecastArray;
    List<String> weekForecast;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //move initialization here
        //nothing can be executed after return statement
        forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
                "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68"};
        weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `forecastArray` is declared:

- Inside `onCreateView`
- After the `return` statement.

**Nothing** will execute after a `return` statement (unless it's in a `finally` block, but don't worry about that for right now).

It looks like you are trying to make the list as an instance field for your class; to do that, you need to move the curly brace to before the `forecastArray` declaration, like this:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    } // new location for the }


        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
                "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68"};
    // } was here, not anymore
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just intialize the Array first outside of the constructor

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public string[] forecastArray;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Tuesday - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Wednesday - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Thursday - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Friday - Help Trapped in weather Station  - 60/51",
                "Saturday - Sunny - 80/68"};
    }
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
    );
}
```